# react-native-dropdown-picker Can't selected item from renderlistitem

Tags: react-native, mobile, drop-down-menu, components, lib

#### Hi everyone

I am having trouble that's when I use RenderListItem to customize the list item, I can't click on item in that list, But I can do it on a normal list (without renderlist)

I don't know why

Hope everyone can help me

Thanks

this is my code

```js
/// my state
const [openAgency, setOpenAgency] = useState(false);
const [agencyValue, setAgencyValue] = useState<string | null>(null);
const [agency, setAgency] = useState(DATA_AGENCY);

/// render item

const Item = (props: any) => {
    return (
        <View style={[styles.containerItem]} key={props.item}>

            <Text style={styles.agencyName}>
                {props.item.value}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.addressName}>
                {props.item.address}
            </Text>
        </View>
    )
}
/// dropdown list
<DropDownPicker
     open={openAgency}
     value={agencyValue}
     items={agency}
     setOpen={setOpenAgency}
     setValue={setAgencyValue}
     setItems={setAgency}
     listMode="SCROLLVIEW"
     style={styles.inputDistrict}
     containerStyle={{
        width: "100%",
     }}
     placeholder="Select an Agency"
     selectedItemContainerStyle={{
        backgroundColor: "#84E5FF",
     }}
     listItemLabelStyle={{
        color: "#00355A"
     }}
     selectedItemLabelStyle={{
        color: "#00355A"
      }}
     dropDownContainerStyle={{
        marginTop: 4,
        borderRadius: 10
     }}
    onSelectItem={(item) => {
        console.log(item);
    }}
    renderListItem={(props) => <Item {...props}  />}
    zIndex={100}
   />
```

Answer (score 2):

The props have some methods, can check this [RenderListItem](https://github.com/hossein-zare/react-native-dropdown-picker/blob/5.x/src/components/RenderListItem.js)

DropDownPicker -

```js
renderListItem={props => <Item {...props} />}
```

Custom item component -

```js
const Item = props => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.onPress(props)} activeOpacity={0.5}>
      <View style={styles.ItemContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.ItemItem}>{props.item.label}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure `react-native-gesture-handler` is installed and use this fork , check whether it is working or not :

```
https://github.com/AmirDoreh/react-native-dropdown-picker
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by adding a TouchableOpacity in the custom item as such:

```js
function handleListItemPress(props){
    props.onPress(props);
}

return (
    <DropDownPicker
        renderListItem={(props) => {
            return(<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {handleListItemPress(props)}}><Text>{props.value}</Text></TouchableOpacity>);
        }}
    />
);
```

Add an onPress to the TouchableOpacity and manually call the DropDownPicker's onPress function in your own method. It should now add your custom rendered item to the list!